# eliminating the rows that is queried in subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

I am trying to solve the problem on [db.grussell](https://db.grussell.org/sql/interface.cgi?tn=Tutorial%203&qn=12) the problem statement is to

> List the full names and positions of current employees who have been
>   on any of the courses that Robert Roberts has been on.

what my approach is that I wrote a subquery which output's the value of `courseno` which were took by Robert Roberts, then I use that `courseno` to get the corresponding `empno(employment number)`. Which is further used as a filter in the other tables which is made by joining `jobhistory` and `employee` table. But in the output I don't want to have the row associated with Robert Roberts. However I know that it's coming because in the first subquery the `courseno` associated with robert roberts is used to fetch `empno` hence robert roberts also gets included.

```
SELECT jobhistory.position,employee.surname,employee.forenames
FROM jobhistory
JOIN employee ON employee.empno= jobhistory.empno
WHERE employee.empno = ANY(
     SELECT empno
     FROM empcourse
     WHERE courseno = ANY(
         SELECT courseno
         FROM empcourse
         JOIN employee ON employee.empno = empcourse.empno
             AND employee.surname = 'Roberts'
             AND employee.forenames ='Robert'
         )
    )
    AND jobhistory.enddate IS NULL
```

Jobhistory

```
EMPNO   POSITION                    STARTDATE ENDDATE   SALARY
1       Accounts Manager            12-JAN-76           30000
1       Assistant Accounts Manager  11-FEB-72 12-JAN-76 22000
```

employee

```
EMPNO   SURNAME FORENAMES   DOB         ADDRESS    TELNO    DEPNO
1       Jones   Elizabeth   05-JAN-44   26 Agnews  212-337   1
                                        Shamrock,  
2       Smith   Robert      07-FEB-47   18 Marsh   031 732   1
                                        Street,
```

empcourse

```
 EMPNO   COURSENO
     1        1
     2        2
```

Comment: Add one more condition `AND employee.empno != (select employee.empno from employee where employee.surname = 'Roberts' AND employee.forenames ='Robert' limit 1)`

Comment: hint:  'FROM employee robert JOIN empcourse ON robert.empno=empcourse.empno JOIN employee otheremployee ON empcourse.empno = otheremployee.empno JOIN jobhistory ON otheremployee.empno=jobhistory.empno WHERE robert.emno != otheremployee.empno`

Comment: @jarlh the code can be run on the given link

Comment: @Bogorovich But that's not how we roll